# view pager with SQLite in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-sqlite

I want to show the only limited pages in `ViewPager`. I have retrieve and get count row from SQLite table using the following query.

```
Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("select count(activityObjId) from ActivityObjectList where " + "activityId" + " = ?", new String[]{strDescription});
```

My `count(activityObjId)` is 2 so i want to add 2 images in `ViewPager`. `count(activityObjId)` is 5 so I want to add 5 images in `ViewPager`. Can someone help how to solve this issue. I have tried but getting error.

```
08-06 06:00:04.744  11207-11207/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 0, found: 1 Pager id: com.example.tazeen.classnkk:id/Image_ViewPagers Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page$MyPagerAdapter
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:999)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1918)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1843)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My activity code

```
public void getActivityObjectId_Count() {
        try {
            dbhelper = new MyDbHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();


            Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("select count(activityObjId) from ActivityObjectList where " + "activityId" + " = ?", new String[]{strDescription});
            if (cursor2 != null) {

                cursor2.moveToFirst();

                String strCount_ActivityObjectId = cursor2.getString(0);
                intCount = Integer.parseInt(strCount_ActivityObjectId);

                Log.e("Count", "in getActivityObjectId = " + strCount_ActivityObjectId);
                Log.e("intCount convert ","to  = " + intCount);

            }

            cursor2.close();
            db.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
    Context mContent;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private List<String> testImages = new ArrayList<String>();


    private int[] GalImages = new int[]{
            R.drawable.img_placeholder,
            R.drawable.img_placeholder,
            R.drawable.img_placeholder,
            R.drawable.img_placeholder,
            R.drawable.img_placeholder,
            R.drawable.img_placeholder
    };


    public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        mContent = context;

        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContent.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return 0.9f;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContent);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);


        imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

              return  intCount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {

        return view == ((ImageView) obj);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've return wrong page count to ViewPager. You should return actual page number in your `getCount()` method. In this case, you should return how many images you've add to the `ViewPager`.

Comment: Above in my post i retrieve count of row in integer intCount  , and whatever intCount  means intCount is 5 so 5 images show in view pager .

Comment: Can someone help for this solution .